# How to generate available booking times depending on the appointment duration the user selected

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two drop-downs, one Containing the Service name and the other that services durationOptions, for example Service a has the options for 30 minutes or 60 minute appointments, While Service B has the options for 60,120,180 minutes. When the user selected a Service it automatically adjusts the second drop down. I also have a calendar that allows the user to pick the date too. My goal is to have an ordering system that shows times from 9-5 taking into account the appointments duration and any other appointments booked at that time, for example if the user wants to book a time block of 3 hours I want to only display cards with the next 3 hours free. How would I go about doing this using Dart and Firebase

This is the booking model:

```
class Service {
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final List<DurationOption> durationOptions;

  Service(this.title, this.description, this.durationOptions);
}

class DurationOption {
  final String durationLabel;
  final Duration duration;
  final String price;

  DurationOption(this.durationLabel, this.duration, this.price);
}
```

this is what the firebase collection for services looks like:

[image]

this is the booking dart class code: I have commented where I want to display those clickable cards showing available times:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:mona/pages/models/servies_model.dart';
import 'package:mona/services/auth/db_handler.dart';

//I can allow them to book weekends or on too short notice
//probably block 3 hours from the next point of availability

class Book extends StatefulWidget {
  const Book({super.key});

  @override
  State<Book> createState() => _BookState();
}

class _BookState extends State<Book> {
  String? currentDateSelected;
  final TextEditingController _date = TextEditingController();

  List<Service> services = [];
  //this list now comes from Firebase
  final dbhandler = DBHandler();

  Service? selectedService;

  DurationOption? selectedDurationOption;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchServices(); //filling the list when page gets opened
  }



  Future<void> fetchServices() async {
    List<Service> fetchedServices =
        await dbhandler.fetchServicesFromFirestore();

    setState(() {
      services = fetchedServices;
      selectedService = services[0]; // Initialize with the first service
      selectedDurationOption = selectedService!.durationOptions[0];
    });
  }
  // Inside your widget state class

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double dropdownWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8;
    var availableTimeSlots = getAvailableTimeSlots();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Book',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 60),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: dropdownWidth,
              height: 70, // Set the width to 80% of the screen width
              child: DropdownButton<Service>(
                elevation: 20,
                value: selectedService,
                onChanged: (Service? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedService = newValue;
                    selectedDurationOption = newValue!.durationOptions[0];
                  });
                },
                items:
                    services.map<DropdownMenuItem<Service>>((Service service) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<Service>(
                    value: service,
                    child: Text(
                      service.title,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 70,
              width: dropdownWidth,
              child: DropdownButton<DurationOption>(
                value: selectedDurationOption,
                onChanged: (DurationOption? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedDurationOption = newValue;
                  });
                },

                ///if selectedService is null and Options is empty make the items
                ///an empty list, otherwise use the durationOptions of the selectedList
                ///and map it to a lsit
                items: selectedService != null &&
                        selectedService!.durationOptions.isNotEmpty
                    ? selectedService!.durationOptions
                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<DurationOption>>(
                        (DurationOption durationOption) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<DurationOption>(
                            value: durationOption,
                            child: Text(
                              '${durationOption.durationLabel} - \$${durationOption.price}',
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ).toList()
                    : [],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: TextFormField(
                showCursor: true,
                readOnly: true,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                controller: _date,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today_rounded),
                  iconColor: Colors.black,
                  labelText: "Select Date",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                onTap: () async {
                  DateTime? pickeddate = await showDatePicker(
                      context: context,
                      initialDate: _date.text.isEmpty
                          ? DateTime.now()
                          : DateTime.parse(_date.text),
                      //initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                      lastDate: DateTime(2101));

                  if (pickeddate != null) {
                    setState(() {
                      _date.text = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickeddate);
                      currentDateSelected = _date.text;
                    });
                  }

                  //Here i need to send off to the database that pickeddate
                },
              ),
            ),
          
            Container(
            // Here I want to display a list of clickable cards showing available times
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So the problem to be solved is how to make cards showing only available times that automatically change when the user selected a different duration while taking into account other bookings made.